# How to record the packets after iptables?

Tags: iptables, pcap, tcpdump

I want to record the packets (using tcpdump) after iptables, but it seems that tcpdump will record all the packets. I don't want the packet dropped by iptables.

Is there any way to

- record the packets after iptables? or
- output the packets (processing by iptables) into pcap/log file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tcpdump acts before iptables for inbound traffic, but you can use iptables "NFLOG" extension to reach your goal: http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html#lbDI

Using "NFLOG" destination you can log desired packets to userspace application, and that's where tcpdump belongs (you can also assign traffic to a specific group and then tell tcpdump to listen from it).

Webserver (very basic) example, let's pretend you are accepting http/https traffic and dropping ssh:

```
#BASIC RULES
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j DROP

#NFLOG REDIRECT ONLY HTTP TRAFFIC
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j NFLOG

#TCPDUMP ONLY ON MATCHED TRAFFIC (=HTTP)
tcpdump -i nflog
```